# Adding a macerator pump toilet

Tags: plumbing

I am considering converting a small laundry room/storage area into a half bath and laundry room. Our house is on a concrete slab, no crawl space or basement. I am considering adding a maceration pump toilet, and adjacent hand washing sink near a new stacked washer & dryer. Is it OK to use the existing washing machine discharge plumbing pipe? I would connect the washer discharge to one of the maceration pump inlets, the hand washing sink to the 2nd pump inlet then discharge everything  into the existing plumbing pipe. Does this sound like it would be an acceptable arrangement?

Comment: You'd want to connect downstream of the trap, of course. And I'd worry about a clog causing sewage to spray back into your washing machine. Doesn't sound like a great connection point unless you are going to close off the leg going to the washer.